# Highcharts :Column chart with percentage grouping on X-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I am a newbie with Highcharts.
I want to display a column chart with, on the X axis, percentages grouped by range. The specifications :
[image]

My data are like this :

```
serie.value: { 14.7575,3.6641,29.0399,19.6646,25.3845,33.3075,12.6064 ...}
```

Each value in this array is a percentage. The chart must show the occurrence number in each percentage range. by example for the datas above, we have 1 in the range 1% - 3%, 3 occurence in the range 10% - 30%, ... So : x-axis : percentage ranges categories and y-axis : occurence number.

I  have categories like these :

```
 categories: ['0% - 0.01%', '0.01% - 0.03%','0.03% - 0.1%','0.1% - 0.3%', '0.3% - 1%','1% - 3%', '3% - 10%','10% - 30%',  '30% - 50%' ]
```

Is it possible to have such a chart without working on the data before (data grouping) ?Is There options to set on my chart options (on the axis  by example ?)

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use x-axis with categories and series with type - column:

```
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [...]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: [...]
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pgw4kdb2/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but i think i  am not clear in my explanations ... i have added precisions in my initial post.

Comment: Hi @Hulkito Nol, Ok - there is no such mechanism in Highcharts, but you can preprocess your data. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rpcfktsh/

Comment: Great ! thank you very much for the detailled example :-)